# Проблема с эмуляцией клика по кнопке Selenium, JS, Python, Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, юнит-тесты, selenium-webdriver

Задача сэмулировать клик по кнопке «Проверено» на хитром UX. button “Проверено» имеет свойство срабатывать при клике правой кнопкой мыши, как и левой кнопкой. С button «В брак» такого нет. Все элементы с динамическими атрибутами, поэтому был сделан скрипт поиска элемента по тексту в нем .

В Selenium click() не срабатывает ни по какой кнопке. Пробовал реализовать через driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text
Цепочки событий ActionChains(driver)
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector
с дальнейшим click() по элементу, не сработало нигде на этих страницах

Тогда я воткнул JS код через driver.execute_script и это сработало, везде кроме button “Проверено»

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let link = document.querySelectorAll('label'); 
  link = Array.from( link ).filter( e => (/Элемент1/i).test( e.textContent ) );
  link[0].click(); 
});
```

или такой вариант , равнозначный.

```
const buttonNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
const links = Array.from(buttonNodes).filter(e => (/Элемент1/i).test( e.textContent ))
links[0].click()
```

Скрипт ищет все элементы по тегу, добавляет в массив, фильтрует и кликает.

Меняем тег и текст, все прекрасно работает на кнопках «В брак» и «ок». Но не работает с проверено, хотя outerHTML одинаковый по структуре

```
const buttonNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button')
const links = Array.from(buttonNodes).filter(e => (/В брак/i).test( e.textContent ))
links[0].click()
```

OuterHTML кнопки проверено

```
<button class="x-btn-text" type="button" style="position: relative; width: 94px;" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">Проверено<img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%9E%20%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%A4%D0%90%D0%9F_files/clear_002.gif" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(&quot;https://192.168.80.2:6780/WebModule/vf2011/01B9092B7306E43EFF062BE4A1F4F390.cache.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll -798px -192px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 4px;" role="presentation" class=" x-btn-image" border="0"></button>
```

OuterHTML кнопки в брак

```
<button class="x-btn-text" type="button" style="position: relative; width: 94px;" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">В Брак<img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%9E%20%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%A4%D0%90%D0%9F_files/clear_002.gif" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(&quot;https://192.168.80.2:6780/WebModule/vf2011/01B9092B7306E43EFF062BE4A1F4F390.cache.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll -798px -168px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 4px;" role="presentation" class=" x-btn-image" border="0"></button>
```

`console.log(typeof links[0])` выдает **Object**

`console.log(links[0] instanceof(HTMLElement))` выдает **False**
Такой же ответ выдается и на кнопке «В брак», хотя она срабатывает.

Передавал в Python return links[0] , запрашивал принт элемента, его координаты и размер, вот что сообщает:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="052cc0daa6975bc23282c08ce26fc5fa", element="106630e2-439a-4e47-b03f-d4fb6641ec46")> 1592 650 {'height': 32, 'width': 94}
```

Пробовал также сделать в Selenium эмуляцию клика со сдвигом по пикселям через move_to_element , move_by_offset, бесполезно

Какие идеи? Сделать клик по пикселям в JS? На крайняк эмулировать клавиши Tab и Enter, что замедлит работу аппы во много раз (более 30 событий нужно + все поедет при правках UI) и тоже не факт что сработает.

Comment: Самого главного мы и не увидели - код и работа этой кнопки "проверено".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что фронт собирали на GWT, да так криво получилось, что событие висит только на mousedown на родителе пятого поколения кнопки button O_O Этот родитель является таблицей в которой вложено еще несколько десятков "пустых" элементов.
Проблему решил таким JS скриптом:

```js
var buttonNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button') //ищем все элементы по тегу
var links = Array.from(buttonNodes).filter(e => (/Проверено/i).test( e.textContent )) //ложим в массив и фильтруем по тексту в кнопке
var link= links[0] //выделяем первый найденный элемент
parent = link.parentNode;  //ищем родителей
parent2 = parent.parentNode;
parent3 = parent2.parentNode;
parent4 = parent3.parentNode;
parent5 = parent4.parentNode;
var clientRect = parent5.getClientRects() //выделяем координаты элемента
clientX = clientRect[0].x
clientY = clientRect[0].y
var o = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); //создаем событие по координатам
o.initMouseEvent( 'mousedown', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, clientX, clientY, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
parent5.dispatchEvent(o);
```